# Custom Field Value not saving on sales_flat_quote & sales_flat_order

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, sales-order, save

I have created a custom field from `sales_flat_quote` & `sales_flat_order` tables and in checkout page have field called `delivery_date`. When an order is being placed, it's not saving my custom field value.

**My code is:**

**`etc/modules/Easylife_Ats.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Ats>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Easylife_Ats>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**`Ats/etc/config.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Ats>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Easylife_Ats>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ats>
                <class>Easylife_Ats_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>ats_resource</resourceModel>
            </ats>
            <ats_resource>
                <class>Easylife_Ats_Model_Resource</class>
            </ats_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <ats>
                <class>Easylife_Ats_Block</class>
            </ats>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <ats>
                <class>Easylife_Ats_Helper</class>
            </ats>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <ats_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Easylife_Ats</module>
                </setup>
            </ats_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
          <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
                <observers>
                    <ats>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>ats/observer</class>
                        <method>saveCustomData</method>
                    </ats>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>

        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**`Ats/Model/Observer.php`**

```
<?php

class Easylife_Ats_Model_Observer
{

    public function saveCustomData(Varien_Event $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $fieldVal = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
        Mage::log($fieldVal);
        $order->setDeliveryDate($fieldVal['delivery_date']);
    }
}
```

**`Ats/sql/ats_setup/installer-0.1.0.php`**

```
<?php

/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
require_once('app/Mage.php');

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');

$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'backend_type' => 'varchar',
    'frontend_input' => 'varchar',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label' => 'Delivery Date',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => '0',
    'comparable' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false
);

$installer->addAttribute('order','delivery_date',$attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('quote','delivery_date',$attribute);

$installer->endSetup();
```

**`design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method.phtml`**

```
<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional') ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="delivery_date" name="delivery_date" value="" class="input-text" type="text">
```

**`design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\info.phtml`**

```
<?php if($_order->getDeliveryDate()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delivery Date') ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value"><strong><?php echo $_order->getDeliveryDate(); ?></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Can you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Do you see the column `delivery_date` in the tables `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_order`? If so, try clearing the cache. Even if the cache is disabled the table schema cache still exists.

Comment: @Marius, Yah! created. I seen.

Comment: @Marius, not saving value even I cleared cache.

Comment: @Marius, Any suggestions.

Comment: Not for now. Sorry.

Comment: There is a datetime type, why aren't you using it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the attribute to the quote to order service model configuration:

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>
            <delivery_date>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </delivery_date>
        </sales_convert_quote>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function code

```
public function saveCustomData(Varien_Event $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $fieldValobj = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();
    if($fieldValobj)
    {
        $fieldVal = $fieldValobj->getParams();
    }
    Mage::log($fieldVal);
    $order->setDeliveryDate($fieldVal['delivery_date']);
}
```

otherwise it will give Fatal Error

Comment: I don't think this is needed. One can be quite sure, that a request object exists