# rewrite Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract?

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, php-5.4

I'm new to magento, I'm rewrite the `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` class. But it's not calling?

**my code is:**

**config.xml**

```
....
 <models>
<shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <carrier_abstract>Easylife_ThirdParty_Model_Carrier_Abstract</carrier_abstract>
                </rewrite>
            </shipping>
 </models>
..
```

**//abstract.php**

```
<?php

class Easylife_ThirdParty_Model_Carrier_Abstract extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){
        Mage::log('Collect Rates');
        return parent::collectRates($request);
    }

    public function getMethodPrice($cost, $method = '')
    {
        //get the session
        Mage::log('get Method Price');
        return $method == $this->getConfigData($this->_freeMethod)
        && $this->getConfigFlag('free_shipping_enable')
        && $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal') <= $this->_rawRequest->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()
            ? '0.00'
            : $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost);
    }

}
```

It's not calling. Is this Correct/Not?
If not how can I rewrite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manoj ,you can

```
not overwrite any abstract class in php.
```

If you want to   modify Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract class then  copy `Mage>Shipping>Model>Carrier>Abstract.php` to `app>code>local>Mage>Shipping>Model>Carrier>Abstract.php`
Or

Comment: Can you look on this thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23761/custom-field-value-not-saving-on-sales-flat-quote-sales-flat-order. Any seggesions.

Comment: let see..........